# Create simple register and login system and get error 500

Tags: php, internal-server-error

i will try to explain this error. I have 2 websites, and i create simple login and register system. When i uploaded on first website, everything work nice, then i uploaded on second website just change config file and phpmailer configuration and get 500 error. This system work on first website and on second website i get that error. I read on this website answers and google but not helping me. Anyone have solution? I don't have yet .htaccess file so that is not problem... I already try to get error using .htaccess file entering code `php_flag display_errors 1` but only get `Invalid command 'php_flag', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration` this error.

Thanks

Comment: Your web server (Apache?) and PHP logs will show you exactly what happened.  What do they say?

Comment: On error page only this say me: Invalid command 'php_flag', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration... @Don'tPanic